# Embedding of symmetric groups into orthogonal groups

Tags: group-theory, permutations, lie-groups, symmetric-groups, group-actions

Let $\Sigma_n$ be the symmetric group of order $n$. Let $O(N)$ be the orthogonal group acting on $\mathbb{R}^N$.

**Question:** Given a fixed $N$, how to find the maximal $n$ such that $\Sigma_n$ can be embedded as a subgroup of $O(N)$? I have tried examples and guess the answer is $n=N+1$. But I cannot prove...

Comment: Why do you think $n=N+2$? The smallest degree of a faithful complex representation of $S_n$ is $n-1$. In fact that representation is real and orthogonal, so $n=N+1$ is the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks! I have not learned representation theory. could you explain more in detail?

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't have time to do that right now, Perhaps someone else can help.

Comment: The $N$ simplex has $N+1$ vertices, which can be fully permuted by orthogonal rotations in $\mathbb{R}^N$.  Induction is your friend in showing this direction of inequality, $n \ge N+1$.

Comment: My comment above has the phrase "orthogonal rotations" but this is a bit misleading as reflections are also needed.  I should have said "orthogonal mappings", but it's too late to edit now!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the $N$ subspace $x_1 + \dots + x_{N+1} = 0$ which is orthogonal to the vector $\vec{1} =\underbrace{(1,\dots, 1)}_{N+1} \in \mathbb{R}^{N+1} $

Then $S_{N+1}$ acts on this subspace and embeds into $O(N+1)$ and yet $\vec{1}$ is preserved, so this action embeds into $O(N)$.  This shows $n \geq N+1$.  This is the same as @hardmath's answer.

---

Showing $n \leq N+1$ is less easy and I am not sure how to do it.  Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^N$.  Then $S_{N+2}$ permutes the $(N+2)!$ vectors 
$\{ gv: g \in S_{N+2}\}\subset \mathbb{R}^N$.  This doesn't seem quite right...

The $(N+2)$-cycle $a =(1,2,\dots, N+1, N+2)$ can act on the vector over and over giving a kind of chain:

$$ v_1 \to v_2 \to \dots \to v_{N+2} \to v_1$$

Since $a^{N+2}=1$, this symmetry rotates the $(N+2)$-gon generated by these vectors, and the panel it lives in.

---

This still seems perfectly fine to me... yet it can't be the case.  E.g. **Why can't we draw a tetrahedron on a sheet of paper so that it preserves all the symmetry it has in 3-dimensions?**  So... how come $S_4$ can't embed into $O(2)$, the rotation group in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$? I think $S_4$ has a 4-cycle - preserving a square embedded in the unit circle.  It also has a 3-cycle - preserving an equilateral triangle in the same circle.  The only symmetry to preserve both shapes.

Also, it's instructive to visualize the order-4 symmetry of the tetrahedron corresponding to the action of the 4-cycle (1,2,3,4).

How to show $S_5$ can't be embedded into rotations in $SO(3)$ preserving the unit sphere $S^2$?  In fact, the symmetries of the [icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_symmetry) - isomorphic to the alternating group $A_5$ -  comes close.

Comment: @haohaoxuexi:  I think it would be better to add your answer below.  Other Readers will benefit from your discovery.

Comment: Sorry. My solution is problematic.